# How to set the height of a widget dynamically in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

```
Container(    
height: min(
                widget.order.products.length * 20.0 + 10,
                100,
              ),)
```

widget.order.products.length => will return me the list of dynamic products.

While viewing the list of these products, I want the set the height of the container dynamic which I'm not able to do with the "min" function.

Can anyone help me.
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using an IntrinsicHeight:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicHeight-class.html

A widget that sizes its child to the child's intrinsic height.

This class is useful, for example, when unlimited height is available and you would like a child that would otherwise attempt to expand infinitely to instead size itself to a more reasonable height.

The constraints that this widget passes to its child will adhere to the parent's constraints, so if the constraints are not large enough to satisfy the child's maximum intrinsic height, then the child will get less height than it otherwise would. Likewise, if the minimum height constraint is larger than the child's maximum intrinsic height, the child will be given more height than it otherwise would.

This van be put Around things like a listView, Column etc.